# Setting up Sinatra with RVM & Apache (passenger)

Tags: ruby, apache, sinatra, passenger, rvm

Are there any instructions anywhere on how to set up Sinatra with RVM and Apache (passenger)?
(Normal ruby is 1.8.7; RVM should turn it into 1.9.2 on the apache server.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Deploying a Rack based Ruby application](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application) (from Passenger for Apache docs)
- [RVM Passenger integration](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/) (from the RVM site)

Basically, Passenger 3 uses the RVM settings that were in effect when the installer was run as its default Ruby. In other words, if you installed RVM with 1.9.2 before installing Passenger, Passenger should be using RVM's 1.9.2 Ruby automagically. Just make a `config.ru` and vhost as described is the Passenger docs.